# How to filter mongodb collection by a calculated property

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a model called `SearchableOrder` defined like this:

```
public class SearchableOrder
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

    public string MarketplaceCode { get; set; }

    public DateTime ShippingDeadline { get; set; }
}
```

The functionality I'm tasked to implement is to allow our users to do some dynamic filtering. For example a user may want to filter only by the `MarketplaceCode` property or both by the `MarketplaceCode` property AND the `ShippingDeadline` property. This means that I can't just write a hardcoded query, but I instead need to build mongo filters on the fly. It's easy for fields present in this model, for example the filter built for the `MarketplaceCode` property and Operator == Equals would look like:

```
Builders<SearchableOrder>.Filter.Eq(o => o.MarketplaceCode, "MyMarketplaceCode");
```

The trouble begins if I want (and in fact need) to give users the possibility to filter by some "complex" criteria. For example a user may want to get all the orders whose `ShippingDeadline` is in X days. I browsed frenzily through the mongo docs and then through the c# driver docs and found out that the `$where` operation is what I want. Or is it?
When I use this code:

```
const int MillisecondsInADay = 86400000;
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var days = 5; // received from the user input
Builders<SearchableOrder>.Filter.Where(o => (o.ShippingDeadline - now) / MillisecondsInADay > days);
```

I get this exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: (({document}{ShippingDeadline} - 24.06.2021 15:50:45) / 86400000) is not supported.` which is thrown by `MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.GetFieldExpression(Expression expression)`. Any ideas? Mongo docs mention (and I checked it in a raw mongo query and it worked) that I can use a `$where` operation along with a javascript function, but the c# driver's `Where` method seems to not be able to translate the c# code into mongo js. Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need $where. The filter can be  "calculated" on the application level. The condition`(o.ShippingDeadline - now) / MillisecondsInADay > days`  is equal to `o.ShippingDeadline< now -5 days`. where `now - 5 days` can be provided as an exact value to mongo.

Comment: I sometimes feel really retarded. It seems you're right. I'll try it tomorrow, with a fresh mind and accept your answer if you post one.

Comment: But just out of curiosity - I can think of other scenarios where my initial approach would be useful, for example doing arithmetic between fields. Would it work then?

Comment: Sure, if you really need to compare 2 fields or expressions you will need to  use aggregation framework. In LINQ terms it's implemented as Queryable  https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_Linq_IMongoQueryable_1.htm